# Chrome extension to mute all but the active tab

Tags: gratis, chrome, audio

I open nearly all my links in new tabs. So, say I just opened a YouTube video, but then found another video on the right hand side that is better, I open it in a new tab, and hear both videos playing at the same time.

So, I'm looking for a chrome extension that:

- can automatically mute all tabs except for the active one
- can *preferably* pause any videos playing in those tabs (optional)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found an extension that **mutes everything but the active tab**.

I tested it on YouTube. When I switched tabs, the other tab muted itself, but unfortunately the extension does not *pause* the video.

It's called [Mute Inactive Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mute-inactive-tabs/fnndlfanhilikkpoginfilaodnnekhhe/), on the Chrome Web Store.

Answer (score 3):

The free Chrome extension [MuteTab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mutetab/nmkbaaijgpppbokgnhhoakihofedkgcc/related) used to be able to do that but it doesn't seem to work anymore, at least for me with YouTube videos.

[image]

As of now, Google Chrome doesn't provide any easy access for extensions to mute a tab:

- [Google explains why it won’t add a ‘mute tab’ option to Chrome, considers Tab Audio API for extensions](http://thenextweb.com/google/2014/02/11/google-explains-wont-add-mute-tab-option-chrome-considers-tab-audio-api-extensions/)
- [Per tabs control over sounds in web pages](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=3541)
- [chrome.tabaudio - New Chrome API Proposal](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1kR1sUg6QOMJDE2c6jZgm15g1L89GuVx7HAGfcIqqbrY/edit#)

Comment: ok, +1. i didn't think of ckecking the Chrome API to see if this was possible.

Comment: I found an extension that works! See my new answer, in case you're interested :)