# Chrome extension to pause music tabs

Tags: audio, chrome

Similar to [Chrome extension to mute all but the active tab](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10654/chrome-extension-to-mute-all-but-the-active-tab) I'm having problems with multiple tabs playing music at the same time. I save all my tabs when closing Chrome. Eventually I end up with **a lot** of YouTube tabs which get loaded when reopening Chrome.

How can I pause "music tabs" (SoundCloud, for example. YouTube videos are also sufficient) or stop loading those tabs when opening Chrome?

The problem with the [Mute Inactive Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mute-inactive-tabs/fnndlfanhilikkpoginfilaodnnekhhe/) extension is, that the music/video gets loaded anyway thus reducing available bandwidth. If I have 20 existing tabs when opening Chrome but actually want to listen to a new one this becomes a serious issue.

Answer (score 1):

## Try [MuteTab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mutetab/nmkbaaijgpppbokgnhhoakihofedkgcc?hl=en)

> Lets you stop or close potentially noisy tabs (or pause if it is YouTube, QuickTime, or HTML5 video.)

[image]

Comment: "Enable autostop background tabs" doesn't work correctly in my case. I have to manually click on it everytime I want to pause/mute backround tabs. Is there an extension that blocks music automatically when you change your current tab. That would be awsome! Tnx.